MS-Access query to show manufacture due orders only
I have a order table tblOrders like below-



POS
POSDate
OrderType
Item
Quantity




107351
11/01/2024
BULK
CL
6300


107352
11/01/2024
BULK
T
4725


107353
11/01/2024
BULK
CL
2685


107354
11/02/2024
BULK
CL
178


107355
11/02/2024
BULK
CL
3061


107356
11/02/2024
BULK
CL
5880


107357
11/02/2024
BULK
CP
11088


107358
11/03/2024
BULK
IL
5824


107359
11/03/2024
BULK
MX
4515


107360
11/03/2024
BULK
CP
6709


107361
11/03/2024
BULK
CL
500


107362
11/04/2024
BULK
HT
4515


107363
11/04/2024
BULK
CL
6948


107364
11/04/2024
REPLACE
CL
878


107365
11/04/2024
BULK
CP
67



and manufacturing details table tblManufacture like-



POS
MDateTime
WCH
ManufactureQty




107351
11/03/2024 3:05:25 PM
15
6300


107354
11/03/2024 5:05:25 PM
15
20


107353
11/03/2024 5:05:25 PM
15
2685


107354
11/04/2024 4:05:25 PM
15
50


107355
11/04/2024 3:05:25 PM
15
3061


107357
11/05/2024 3:05:25 PM
15
11088


107356
11/05/2024 10:05:25 PM
15
5824


107359
11/05/2024 3:05:25 PM
15
2000


107359
11/06/2024 3:05:25 PM
15
1000


107361
11/06/2024 11:05:25 AM
15
83


107362
11/06/2024 3:05:25 PM
15
4515



Using the following query
SELECT tblOrders.POS, 
tblOrders.POSDate, 
tblOrders.OrderType, 
tblOrders.Item, 
tblOrders.Quantity, 
q1.SumOfManufactureQty, 
tblOrders.Quantity-q1.SumOfManufactureQty AS ManufactureDue, 
q1.MaxOfMDateTime, 
q1.WCH
FROM tblOrders INNER JOIN 

(SELECT tblManufacture.POS, tblManufacture.WCH, Sum(tblManufacture.ManufactureQty) AS SumOfManufactureQty, 
Max(tblManufacture.MDateTime) AS MaxOfMDateTime
FROM tblManufacture
GROUP BY tblManufacture.POS, tblManufacture.WCH
HAVING (((tblManufacture.WCH)=15))) as q1 

ON tblOrders.POS = q1.POS
WHERE (((tblOrders.Quantity-q1.SumOfManufactureQty)>0));

I am getting this output.



POS
POSDate
OrderType
Item
Quantity
SumOfManufactureQty
ManufactureDue
MaxOfMDateTime
WCH




107354
11/02/2024
BULK
CL
178
70
108
11/04/2024 4:05:25 PM
15


107356
11/02/2024
BULK
CL
5880
5824
56
11/05/2024 10:05:25 PM
15


107359
11/03/2024
BULK
MX
4515
3000
1515
11/06/2024 3:05:25 PM
15


107361
11/03/2024
BULK
CL
500
83
417
11/06/2024 11:05:25 AM
15



Above output is correct. Problem is query performance too slow. I have more than 1 million records in tblManufacture. Back-end is MSSQL-2014 db and client workstation is on same LAN. Is there any better way to get the same result in faster?

For one, why would you use HAVING instead of WHERE? I'm not sure if the SQL server optimizer is smart enough to optimize this to a WHERE, but HAVING normally removes rows after the query is done aggregating, while WHERE removes rows before aggregation, which might save SQL server a ton of work calculating aggregates that will never be returned.

Yes, where clause execute row level before aggregating. Let me try it and see if it improves performance.
